# How to send key press to a digital reception

Tags: twilio

Is it possible with the twilio API to send a key tone/press to the connected number in case there is a digital reception?

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a number of ways. If using a Dial, you can use the Number verb or Play Verb with digits parameter.

Number Verb:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits

Play Verb:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#attributes-digits